# Delete an object from a Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: javascript, django, fetch-api

How can I delete an object from a Many-to-Many relationship with fetch? how can I change it?

I have a model for users which has many-to-many field users that presents the followers of the same user: (`followers = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="follow")`)

I'm trying to create a button in the profile of a person that other people can click on, and unfollow or follow.

I have an event listener on that button, and let's say, this is the unfollow button and I want to remove the requesting user, who is saved in the variable `user`, from the followers' list of the user whose profile belongs to him.
And the followers' list I can get when I am doing a fetch, and then I am getting all the info of the person whose profile belongs to him (the `post.user`) that the requesting user, the log-in one, wants to unfollow.
My purpose is to update the people who follow after the `post.user`,  - remove the requesting user that wants to unfollow, but still saves all the other people who follow:

```
element2.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {

       fetch(`users/${post.user}`, {
            method: 'PUT */ or DELETE ?*',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                 followers: ??? 
            })
       })
 })
```

I just want to do with a fetch what I can do with Python (`user_profile.followers.remove(requesting_user)`)
How can I remove the requesting user from the many-to-many field? Without deleting the actual object? And with fetch? Can I?

I will appreciate any help!!!

Comment: ```user_profile.followers.remove(requesting_user)``` This should work, it will remove the follower without deleting them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a view like this to process your API call:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import User

def unfollow(request, user_id):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    follower = request.user
    user.follow.remove(follower)
    return JsonResponse({'success': True})
```

In your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Other URL patterns...
    path('users/<int:user_id>/unfollow/', views.unfollow, name='unfollow'),
]
```

I'd change the template a bit to make it clearer instead of adding an eventlistener with Jquery

```
<button onclick="unfollowUser({{ post.user.id }})">
    Unfollow
</button>
```

```
<script>
function unfollowUser(userId) {
    fetch(`{% url 'unfollow' user_id=0 %}`.replace('0', userId), {
        method: 'DELETE',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Handle success response
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle error response
    });
}
</script>
```